# NDSolve a large System of linear ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

I want to solve a 'large' System of ODEs in the form:

$$\frac{d\mathbf{y}(t)}{dt}+M(t)\cdot\mathbf{y}(t)=0 \label{a} \tag{1}$$

Where M is an NxN Matrix, N is in the order of 600 and involves **interpolating functions**.

By just using the brute force approach:

```
NDSolve[{ListofEquations,InitialConditions},{yList},{t,tstart,tend}]
```

where I just give Mathematica the raw list of flattened-out equations. Mathematica fails and suggests me to use:

```
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
```

This leads to an overwhelming long initialization time before the algorithm then starts to solve the Equations (i tracked this by monitoring t). My Question are now:

- How can I provide Mathematica directly a solvable equation-form without the need of the long initialization using `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`. [This Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html) explains the method but i dont see how I can provide a form like $F(y',y,t)=0$ directly
- What is the most efficient (or efficient) way to solve an equation like \ref{a}, where M involves interpolating function?

Comment: Should we assume that there are no symmetries or other additional structures in the equations or initial conditions?

Comment: Have a look at in the section [Transient PDEs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). Even if this is for FEM it does deal with large sets of ODEs.

Comment: Can `M` be diagonalized?

Comment: Have you tried the vector form of `NDSolve`? Something like `NDSolve[{y'[t] + M[t] . y[t] ==0, y[0] == {..}}, y, {t, tstart, tend}]`?